# How can I increase the margins for the R function, pheatmap?

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am plotting a heatmap using pheatmap ([Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/pheatmap.pdf)). I am plotting a matrix in a fairly straightforward way:

```
pheatmap(mat, annotation_col=df, labels_col=rld$Infection_Line, fontsize_row=5, fontsize_col=7)
```

The bottom of my plot is getting cut off so that I can't see the column names at the bottom.  It looks like this: [image]
I have tried to increase the margins using par() and oma(), as well as cexRow=...

I need to make it so that I can see these long column names without reducing my plot size.  I just want to stretch the margin at the bottom down.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, actually I did google it before posting here and I did try these other solutions already. I posted here because those don't seem to have any effect.   These other answers are for heatmap.2.  This is for pheatmap, which is different.

Comment: For future users landed on this thread, refer to this post for your reference: ***[Increase Margin of Pheatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701207/column-labels-cropped-when-using-pheatmap)***

Comment: `heatmap` and `pheatmap` are not the same. One uses base graphics while other uses grid graphics. This is not a duplicate question as the solutions are different. I have added a solution on Masoud's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701207/column-labels-cropped-when-using-pheatmap).

Comment: @rmf You are right. The duplicated answer they marked could not fix this problem.

Comment: I am having the sam problem, any help ?